# Picking a constructor to call

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass( MyClass && );
    template< typename ... T > MyClass( T&& ... );
};
```

How do I differentiate calling between these two constructors? Can I specialize the templated one to just call the original?

Here is the example use case (and is exactly what I am doing in my real code):

```
MyClass c( MyClass { } );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I differentiate calling"?

Comment: It should already work, no? If the argument is an rvalue of type `MyClass`, the first one will be called. Otherwise the second one.

Comment: @nowi Can you back that up with an example?  It calls the correct constructor here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/440adbd9deda0db3.  Most likely what you are seeing is guaranteed copy ellision or NRVO being applied.

Comment: For instance `MyClass c(MyClass{});` will call `MyClass( T&& ... )` because it gets converted to `MyClass c{};`

Comment: @nowi You're not going to be able to.  The language has changed and now there is no temporary and instead the object is directly constructed.  This is a performance win.

Comment: @nowi you need to add default constructor for that since the template one acts like one since you're allowed to have an empty parameter pack.

Comment: `MyClass() = default;`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting in C++17

```
MyClass c( MyClass { } );
```

is always going to call

```
template< typename ... T > MyClass( T&& ... );
```

The reason for this is that there is no temporary object anymore.  Instead the initialization is elided and `c` is directly constructed from the initializer of the "temporary".  That means what you really have now is

```
MyClass c{};
```

This is a good thing though because instead of construct and move, we now just construct which is a performance win.

Comment: For maximum clarity, I'd add that in the above case, the parameter pack is *empty*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an addendum to Nathans answer since you haven't accepted it yet.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    }

    MyClass(MyClass&& rhs) {
        std::cout<< "moving\n";
    }

    template<typename ... T >
    MyClass(T&& ... ts) {
        std::cout << "ctor template\n";
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    MyClass a(MyClass{});       // only default ctor, no move
    std::cout << "---\n";
    MyClass b(MyClass{"bork"}); // only template ctor, no move
    std::cout << "---\n";
    MyClass c = std::move(a);   // plain move
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sQK9rU)